# Finding the Root of a Polynomial over $\mathbb F_{16}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots

Suppose we have the polynomial $p(x) = x^4 + x + 1$ over $\mathbb F_{16}.$  How does one find a root $\alpha$ of $p(x)$?

I have done this for $\mathbb F_2$ by listing and trying every possible element. That approach doesn't seem practical here.

Comment: I am supposed to find the order of $\alpha$, $\alpha$ + 1, and $\alpha$^3.  I don't see how to get there from these answers.  I am only three weeks into my first class on this topic, and have never worked with fields or rings until now.

Comment: From my answer, you immediately get the order of $\alpha$ (except I have written $\beta$). You can also deduce the order of $\alpha^3$ by using the fact that $\alpha^5 = 1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that $16 = 2^4,$ the field $\mathbb F_{16}$ is isomorphic to a quotient of the polynomial ring $(\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z)[x]$ by the ideal generated by an irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ of degree 4. Consequently, for any root $\beta$ of $f(x),$ the evaluation homomorphism $\varphi : (\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z)[x] \to (\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z)(\beta)$ that sends $g(x) \mapsto g(\beta)$ induces an isomorphism $\mathbb F_{16} \cong (\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z)(\beta).$ One can show that $f(x) = x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z,$ so we may identify $\mathbb F_{16}$ with the set $\{a \beta^3 + b \beta^2 + c \beta + d \,|\, a, b, c, d \in \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z \}$ with $\beta^4 + \beta^3 + \beta^2 + \beta + 1 = 0.$

Observe that $\mathbb F_{16}$ has characteristic $2,$ hence we have the following identities. \begin{align*} \beta^5 &= \beta (\beta^4) = \beta(\beta^3 + \beta^2 + \beta 
+ 1) = \beta^4 + \beta^3 + \beta^2 + \beta = 1 \\ \\ \beta^6 &= \beta(\beta^5) = \beta \\ \\ \beta^8 &= (\beta^4)^2 = (\beta^3 + \beta^2 + \beta + 1)^2 = \beta^6 + \beta^4 + \beta^2 + 1  = \beta^4 + \beta^2 + \beta + 1 \end{align*} From here, you can show that $\beta^3 + \beta$ is a root of $x^4 + x + 1$ over $\mathbb F_{16}.$

> \begin{align} (\beta^3 + \beta)^4 + (\beta^3 + \beta) + 1 &= \beta^{12} + \beta^4 + \beta^3 + \beta + 1 \\ &= (\beta^6)^2 + \beta^4 + \beta^3 + \beta + 1 \\ &= \beta^4 + \beta^3 + \beta^2 + \beta + 1 = 0 \end{align}

Of course, I do not claim that this is the simplest computation, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

$p(x)=x^4+x+1$ is irreducible over $GF(2)$ and $GF(16) = GF(2)[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$, where $GF(16)$ is generated by a zero $\alpha$ of $p(x)$, i.e.,  $\alpha^4+\alpha+1=0$ in
$GF(16)$.

$p(x)=x^4+x+1$ factors in $GF(16)$ into linear factors,

$p(x) = (x-\alpha)(x-\alpha^2)(x-\alpha^4)(x-\alpha^8)$

by the Frobenius automorphism $a\mapsto a^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x):=x^2+x+1$ is the only irreducible quadratic $\Bbb F_2$ polynomial. $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb F_2$ as it has no roots and $f(x)^2=x^4+x^2+1\neq p(x)$. $$\therefore\;\Bbb F_{16}\approx\frac{\Bbb F_2[x]}{\langle p(x)\rangle}$$

Now, the element $x+\langle p(x)\rangle$ is a root of $p(x)$ after identifying $\Bbb F_2$ with $\{\mathbf 0+\langle p(x\rangle),\mathbf 1+\langle p(x)\rangle\}$ where $$\mathbf 0:=0+2\Bbb Z\;\;\;\;\;\mathbf 1:=1+2\Bbb Z$$

Comment: @Carlo. The OP defined $p(x)$ already as the $\Bbb F_2$ polynomial $x^4+x+1$.

Comment: @Carlo. Each $\Bbb F_2$ polynomial of degree $3$ or less represents a distinct $\langle p(x)\rangle$ coset. The number of such polynomials is $16$.

Comment: @Carlo. You are not using $p(x)$. Check the OP. $p(x)=x^4+x+1$.  NOT $x^4+x^2+1$.

Comment: @Carlo. In my explanation above I first proved that $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb F_2$.  Do you see why now ?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct solution. I failed to realize that $x^4 + x + 1$ is irreducible modulo $2,$ so that makes the problem much easier.

Comment: You probably mean $\mathbf0 := 2\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbf 1 := 1+2\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @azif00. That's right.